# Where can I find the in-depth LPC2132 datasheet?

Tags: datasheet, arm

I have searched high and low on Google for the user manual about the LPC2132 ARM chip. So far, all I have come up with is the ARM7TDMI manual and a short (41 pages) overview of the LPC2132 chip.

However, I'm looking for a more detailed description of the various parts of the micro controller, such as register addresses and peripheral information. I have found several promising links, but the PDF documents appear to be broken

Can anyone point me to the full length LPC2132 data sheet?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The latest user manual for the LPC213x family can be downloaded [here in PDF format](http://ics.nxp.com/support/documents/microcontrollers/pdf/user.manual.lpc2131.lpc2132.lpc2134.lpc2136.lpc2138.pdf).

**Note: This is rev 02 -- the URL posted by pingswept above (no fault of his own) is the earlier rev 01 version.**

**Disclaimer:** I consulted for NXP and the engineers inside the company are incredibly frustrated with the website organization at NXP.

Comment: Well done, sir!

Comment: Glad the info was helpful.  Finding the correct info, or any info at all for that matter, can be a challenge with NXP.  But their chips are (IMO) the best bang-for-the-buck when it comes to ARM7 & Cortex M3/M0.

Comment: NXP indeed has a very annoying site.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the 270 page beast: http://www.nxp.com/documents/user_manual/UM10120.pdf